# How to set Initial Points for optimization problems

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

How to set Initial Points for optimization problems in MMA?

In this case,we do not need to set the range of the variable x1, x2.

```
fgoal = (1 - x1)^2 + 100*(x2 - x1^2)^2;
fcon1 = x1^2 + x2^2 <= 1;

fcon2 = x1 + 3 x2 <= 5;

NMinimize[{fgoal, fcon1, fcon2}, {x1, x2}, 
 Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> {1.3, 0.5}}]
```

It returns:

[image]

Comment: As we know `NMinimize` always attempts to find a global minimum subject to the constraints given. Therefore we don't need to restrict initial point. In turn with `FindMinimum[{fgoal, fcon1, fcon2}, {{x1, 1.3}, {x2, .5}}]` we can get local extremum.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fgoal = (1 - x1)^2 + 100*(x2 - x1^2)^2;
fcon1 = x1^2 + x2^2 <= 1;
fcon2 = x1 + 3 x2 <= 5;
```

The "InitialPoints" are expected to be a `List` of points. Even if you only provide one point, that point must be in a `List`

```
sol1 = NMinimize[{fgoal, fcon1, fcon2}, {x1, x2}, 
  Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> {{1.3, 0.5}}}]

(* {0.0456748, {x1 -> 0.786415, x2 -> 0.617699}} *)
```

For this problem, no option is needed

```
sol2 = NMinimize[{fgoal, fcon1, fcon2}, {x1, x2}]

(* {0.0456748, {x1 -> 0.786415, x2 -> 0.617699}} *)
```

Or the problem can be done exactly with [`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html)

```
sol3 = Minimize[{fgoal, fcon1, fcon2}, {x1, x2}] // RootReduce

(* {Root[6544214292004000000 - 144368235817268120000 # + 
  24470854590692601200 #^2 - 13682324808464174004 #^3 + 
  6947692863550867001 #^4 - 216684553251678400 #^5 + 
  2560711072960000 #^6 - 13311744000000 #^7 + 25600000000 #^8& , 1, 
  0], {x1 -> 
   Root[-1 - 198 # + 30200 #^2 + 598 #^3 - 70599 #^4 - 400 #^5 + 
    10400 #^6 + 40000 #^8& , 5, 0], 
  x2 -> Root[-10000 - 20200 # + 59800 #^2 + 120800 #^3 - 99399 #^4 - 
    220600 #^5 + 9600 #^6 + 120000 #^7 + 40000 #^8& , 4, 0]}} *)

sol3 // N

(* {0.0456748, {x1 -> 0.786415, x2 -> 0.617698}} *)
```

Comment: which options for display iter-detailed in MMA?

Comment: I do not understand your question. If you are asking how you would know that the option value must be a `List`, it is implicit in the option name: `InitialPoints`. An unspecified number of points (plural) could only be passed in a `List`; and things which can be lists are usually lists (e.g., output of `Solve` and similar functions are a list of solutions even when there is only a single solution).